# Output produced by Python numpy.percentile() not same as MATLAB prctile()

Tags: python

The value of percentile produced by Python is not same as the one in MATLAB

I used `numpy.percentile` in Python and `prctile` in MATLAB.

Python:

```
a = [   4.17844459 3020.84958224    0.        ]
b = [20 50 80]
c = [0, [0,  1, 2]] = np.percentile(a, b)
```

[1.6713778362648797 4.178444590662199 1814.1811271801632]

```
MATLAB:
c(1, 1:3) = prctile(a, b)
```

[0.417844459066220  4.17844459066220    2719.18246847491]

I prefer the answer from MATLAB since this is coming from the original code that I'm trying to do in Python.

Comment: That is not even syntactically valid Python.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Try to put any of the lines under "Python:" into a Python interpreter, and Python will report a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 3):

At its core, this is a "sample" vs "population" issue.

NumPy treats `a` as representing an entire population, so the lowest element is the 0th percentile and the highest element is the 100th percentile, and bases its interpolation on that. Interpolation defaults to linear, but other options are available.

In contrast, for an `n`-element vector, Matlab treats the elements as ranging from the `100*.5/n`th percentile to the `100*(n-.5)/n`th percentile, and bases its interpolation on that. This is more appropriate for approximating percentiles in an unknown population, when all you have is a sample. Interpolation is linear, except for percentiles below `100*.5/n` or above `100*(n-.5)/n`, where Matlab returns the lowest or highest input data points respectively.

Neither NumPy nor Matlab offers a toggle to get the opposite behavior. If you want Matlab's behavior in Python, you will have to either sort your input and perform interpolation manually, or translate the percentiles you ask for to undo the effects of the different input interpretation:

```
def matlab_percentile(x, p):
    p = numpy.asarray(p, dtype=float)
    n = len(x)
    p = (p-50)*n/(n-1) + 50
    p = numpy.clip(p, 0, 100)
    return numpy.percentile(x, p)
```